# Visualization of boolean Parameters in Python GUI

Tags: python, pandas, parameter-passing, real-time

I have an excel list with boolean paramaters, that were tracked every second for 4h. My goal is it to highlight a specific area of the picture, if the related parameter turns from 0 to 1. There should be a real time counter in the programm.

The problem is that I dont know how to simualate a real time process with dynamic boolean parameters. That would be the first step. I just need some ideas as a starting point.

[exampletable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ailUn.png)

Comment: what do you want? real-time, or read from excel file...and what do you mean with "my goal is to highlight a specific area of the picture" , is this in the python gui, or in the excel. So many questions...its not clear what you want.

Comment: Sorry for the bad description. I uploaded an example table to the post. I want to import the data from the excel list via pandas. After that I want to visualize the different parameters in a GUI in real time. For example: parameter A has a change at 01:00 -> at this moment the program should color in the left side of the window with black( just as an example). The left side shoukld stay black until Parameter A changes to 1.

Comment: but whats real time about that? you are reading in a file already? and how will you determine the time then? As in, its 01:00 now, so lets replay what happened.

Comment: I meant with real time that the program shows the parameters like they were in the real test environment. Something more detailed information:I have built a component , that has 3 LED lamps on it and i have tracked every 1/4 second if each LED is on or off. Now i want to create a GUI that can virtually show the actual status of the lamps at every time. I hope that answered your question, that I didn't understand to 100 % ( english it not my motherlanguage).

Comment: What do you mean by how do I determine the time?